# vb.net enter key press on a button

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a form with a button and when i click TAB key the button got selected but when I click ENTER key this code is not executed.My code is,

```
Private Sub Button1_Keypress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Button1.KeyPress
If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
 MsgBox("DO SOMETHING") 
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: to click a button you should use space key ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have anything to code..
If your focus is on a button and you press ENTER, the `Button1_Click` event will fire..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("DO SOMETHING")
End Sub
```

That's the case if your focus is on the button. And if ever you wish to fire your event wherever your focus is, the your code should be fitted in the Form1_KeyPress() event

Comment: Oh yes I get confused with click and enter key press.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24335830/4321985)

Code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```

it work for me.