# Button Click Equals to Press Enter Key on the Keyboard

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I would like to equal a click on Button1 to press the Enter key on the keyboard, how can I do that? Can you provide me the code please?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Set the `AcceptButton` property of your form to be `Button1`

[Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is what he's looking for:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

End Sub
```

As I understand it he wanted a button to press Enter for him, not that the button would be activated when pressing Enter.